# simplepie throwing up error messages on site

Tags: simplepie

I have had a simplepie feed on a website for a number of years.  All of a sudden it is throwing up a lot of errors.  See this page to see what I mean: http://flowers-lincoln.co.uk/florist-shop-lincoln.php.  Does anyone know if this is likely to be an issue with depreciated code?  The webhosting company was recently taken over, so the site has moved servers - I'm wondering if this may have caused the issue.
Any guidance would be really appreciated.
Many thanks
Vicky

I'm answering my own question in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.

The problem was caused by a PHP upgrade on our hosting server. I added this to the script

```
ini_set('display_errors','0');
```

and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Those are Strict mode warnings, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php. E_STRICT was not included in E_ALL before PHP 5.4.0. Either configure your PHP to not include E_STRICT in the `error_reporting` value … or fix your script :-)

Comment: @CBroe - you should post as an answer since it looks like that's it.